# how to create user defined function in Java Exception handaling

Tags: java

how to create user defined function in java exception handaling

Comment: What on Earth are you asking here?

Comment: You will definitely need to clarify your question. Are you asking how to create a new Exception?

Comment: Are you referring to extend the Exception class, to throw a new instance of your exceptions, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
  // some code that may raise an exception
} catch (SomeException e ) {
  // any code you like here, which may be a call to a method of any object
  MyHandler h = new MyHandler();
  h.handleIt(e);
}
```